# Published css/js files return 404 in azure portal

Tags: javascript, css, azure, http-status-code-404

I am new to azure, I created a app service and published my app using publish profile option in visual studio, but in my app css js files were returning 404

sample css path is like this

```
 <link href="/Content/melon/assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

is there anything i have to set in config file to load css js files

Comment: Please check if bundling is enabled when you publish your website.

Answer (score 1):

You can login the Kudu console site of your App Serivces (url should be `https://<your_side_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`), or login the App Service Editor (url should be `https://<your_site_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/`) to check whether if you have the file on the particular path. And, you can try to simply put or upload the files into the path. Or you can do some modification on your problem static files in VS.

Right click the problem static files and select the `propertities` button, and change the `Copy to Output Directory` dropdown to `Copy Always`.
[image]

Any update, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I've read about this problem a while ago and I put a note into my Onenote saying: **"Check webroot path set in project.json if linked files throw 404"** - Maybe it'll help you